# Una función para cada argumento, o una función para todos pero con opciones dentro

Tags: c, funciones

En lenguaje C, mi duda es si es mejor esto:

```
funcion(1); //llamando función, con argumento 1
función(2); //lamando función, con argumento 2
...
void funcion(int op){
    switch(op){
        case 1: ... break;
        ...
        default: ... break;
    }
 }
```

o esto:

```
funcion_1(); //llamando función para 1
funcion_2(); //llamando función para 2
...
void funcion_1(void){
    ...
}
void funcion_2(void){
    ...
}
```

en términos ya sea de formato, de sintaxis, o qué es mejor para el compilador o cuál es más rápida, alguien podría explicarme las diferencias? O si se puede hacer una función que acepte un argumento de cualquier tipo de dato, y se programe la función para que lo convierta al dato que sea desea regresar

Gracias de antemano, espero estarme explicando bien

Comment: que hace esa funcion? que es mejor en que aspecto? como se usan dichas funciones? antes de poder contestar algo asi, es muy importante saber para que.

Comment: imagina que esa función hace cualquier cosa, es que mi pregunta es en aspecto general, o sea que me digan en qué casos pero ya le entendí a Juan Sebastián Vargas, gracias igualmente

Comment: Para la suma, tendrías que hacer, `sumar_1()`, `sumar_2()`, de modo que, para cubrir mil números, tendrías que hacer mil funciones, y para un millón de números, un millón de funciones, lo cual se vuelve cada vez más imposible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las ventajas de la programación es la reutilización del código, las funciones fueron idealizadas para una reutilización. Creo que la pregunta no es ¿qué es mejor? sino, ¿qué debo hacer en este caso? Es ahí donde decides cómo plantear tu código.

Si necesitas 2 resultados y les debes hacer el mismo "tratamiento", crea una sola función para reutilizar el código, pero si son parámetros de tipos diferentes que te servirán para aspectos diferentes no tendría sentido usar la misma función.

Al llamar una función dos veces con diferentes parámetros reutilizas código, siempre trata de pensar en reutilizar el código.

Comment: he comprendido Juan muchas gracias

Comment: La parte clave de esta respuesta está en la primera linea del segundo párrafo, independientemente de si quieres reutilizar el código, las funciones solo _deben_ ser creadas para dividir los problemas grandes en problemas más pequeños con el objetivo de reducir la complejidad y la necesidad de cambiar _todo_ el código en caso de haber algún problema, véase [este enlace](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/356672).